# why Generic types only for Object?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

What I mean is

```
interface A <T> {
}

class AImpl implements A < Integer > { // why not A< int >
}
```

I have read this [article](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=967900.968162&preflayout=flat) and googled it but still I have no idea why it is only for Object and not for primitive data types(int, void)?

Comment: In your question there is nothing about WildCards only generic type argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just wildcards - Java generics simply don't support primitive types as type arguments at all.

See the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more information about Java Generics in general, and [this question in particular](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#Are%20primitive%20types%20permitted%20as%20type%20arguments%3f).

Comment: Any insights regarding why it wasn't designed to support primitive types?

Comment: @Eyal: This way didn't require any JVM changes. Personally I wish it *had* been designed more like .NET generics, but such is life.

Answer (score 0):

Generics don't work for int, float, boolean, etc. because primitive types do not have all of the associated metadata and structures that Object based types have. In Java primitive types are just that, primitive.  All of that associated metadata enables things like generics, reflection, subclassing, etc.